# How to write a where in clause based on a collection of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write this AR query that will be a WHERE IN clause:

```
User.include(:country).where(:country_id, @countries).order(:...).limit(10)
```

where @countries could be any result form a AR query:

```
@countries = Country.find(...)
```

How can I make it so it will be like:

```
WHERE country_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.include(:country).where('country_id IN (?)', @countries.map(&:id))...
```